# How to attache a String in generated sequence number

Tags: oracle, jpa

In my application, I am using Struts2 for UI and JPA for DAO layer. And Oracle 11G database.

In my database I have created a sequence ..

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "PERK"."EMP_CODE_SEQ"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 501 CACHE 500 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

Now my requirement is changed. As per the requirement I want to attache "TMP" to my generated  sequence number.

For example : If my sequence no is : 1 then It will give me TMP000001.

For this the SQL query will be like this ..

```
select 'TMP'||lpad(EMP_CODE_SEQ.nextval,6, '0') test from dual;
```

But is there any way to implement the above query in JPA ? OR is there any way in ORACLE,so we can change the output sequence?

Answer (score 4):

> OR is there any way in ORACLE,so we can change the output sequence?

No. Sequence is used to generate a number sequence only. So you cannot force it to generate anything else except numbers. To that end you will need to use implicit or explicit data type conversion and concatenation to produce a string of desired format. As an alternative, you can use `to_char` function to convert number generated by a sequence to left-zero padded string.

```
SQL> select to_char(sq_id.nextval, '000000') res
  2    from dual
  3  /

  RES
-------
 000004
```

Concatenation (bars or `concat' function):

```
SQL> select 'TMP' || to_char(sq_id.nextval, '000000') res
  2    from dual
  3  /

RES
----------
TMP 000006

SQL> select concat('TMP',to_char(sq_id.nextval, '000000')) res
  2    from dual
  3  /

RES
----------
TMP 000007
```

Comment: :A function is also a better option ,if call if from the java to retieve the desired value?

Comment: Its both :),actually i am thinking ,if this is always be the case why not creating a function and call that function .But nyways the obvious solution is already given by you +1

Comment: @Nicholas : Thanks for the reply.  I am fine with "concat" and "to_char" functions. Here I have used JPA. SO I have implemented it in different way to set the new concated sequence number. I am writing my concatnation code inside the setter method of the employee. So by this way i done need to write a query and a function on DB side.

Comment: @Nicholas : I have posted answer from my view. You can check and give your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by writing the logic in JPA setter method itself. Here is the example of JPA entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MST_EMP")
public class MstEmp implements Serializable, IsEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "EMP_CODE")
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "appEmpSeq", sequenceName = "EMP_CODE_SEQ")  
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "appEmpSeq" )
    private String empCode;


    public MstEmp() {
    }

    public String getEmpCode() {
        return this.empCode;
    }

    public void setEmpCode(String empCode) {        
        this.empCode =  getSequencePrefix(empCode)+empCode;
    }



    /**
     * FUNCTION USED TO GENERATE SEQUENCE PREFIX: TEMP+"REQUIRED ZEROs"+EMP CODE
     * @param empCode
     * @return
     */
    public String getSequencePrefix(String empCode){
        String temp = "TEMP";
        if(empCode.length()<6){
            int zeroCount = 6 - empCode.length();

            for(int index=0;index<zeroCount;index++){
                temp = temp + "0";
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Here .. as while setting the employee code, it will call a function to concat required prefix to  the sequence number.